# Office 365 Outlook has huge fonts - how to make smaller?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I just got a reinstall of Office 365 ProPlus, and I'm trying to change the font size in Outlook so they aren't so huge.

I have three panes: the folders, the list of emails in the selected folder, and the reading pane (on the right).  My view is Single, Folder Pane normal, Reading pane right, To-Do bar off.

The folders are a reasonable sized font.  The Reading pane has a slider bar that allows me to adjust the view size.  Those are great.

The list of emails in the folder are HUGE.  The headers (From, Subject, Received, etc) are large.  The groupings (Date: Today; Date: Yesterday) are large.  The email information and single preview line are large.

I've gone to File, Options, Mail, Stationery and Fonts, and changed everything to 9 point font.

View, View Settings, Other Settings has column, row, and message preview fonts, which have all been set to 8.  Conditional Formatting also has a font, which has been set to smaller (9 pt), for each option in the list (Unread messages, unread group headers, etc.)

The Inbox still has very large fonts, and if I go to a subfolder under it, they are all even larger.  I really don't need the letters a half inch tall on my screen!

So, where else do I look?

Comment: What is your scaling set to and what is your display size and resolution?

Comment: @music2myear for the entire computer?  Scale and layout is 100% for the monitor.  Resolution is 1920 x 1080.  But!  I changed it to 150% and then changed it back to 100% and the font size is reasonable now.  The font sizes are consistent and have a decent size.  Thank you!

Comment: I encountered a similar issue before, you may first try installing all available updates for your Outlook and then see whether the issue continues. You may also try switching to another view, such as the Single or Preview under View tab -> Change View. See whether you see the same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

OS Scaling settings can sometimes get "stuck". Outlook, because of the many different UI elements and how they interact with scaling and other aspects of the display, seems, in my experience, to experience more issues with scaling than other applications.

The simplest fix is to change the system scaling setting to any other value, log off and back on, and then set them back to the desired value and, again, log off and back on.

If this doesn't resolve the problem, removing the graphics driver by deleting the Display Adapter from the Device Manager, and then restarting the computer and either allowing Windows to find and install the current driver, or finding the most recent driver, and downloading and installing it, should resolve the issue.